# Duplicate @id with json

Tags: json, schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I have placed in the head section json script - "@type" AutmotiveBusiness, describing business with unique "@id" - https://URL/#AutomotiveBusiness. Normally, in this case it will be visible on all of the subwebpages and it is.

Now I want to add breadcrumbs on the webpages in the following way so I can specify that subwebpage belongs to **https://URL/#AutomotiveBusiness**:

```
@type ListItem
position 1
item 
@id https://URL/#AutomotiveBusiness

@type ListItem
position 2
item
@type AboutPage
```

The problem is when I do this in the mentioned way, the head section from subwebpage disappear when checked in the google structured data testing tool. I understand that here it's the same rule which apply to ID's in CSS.

I am wondering what can I do so the subwebpage will be clearly assigned to the **https://URL/#AutomotiveBusiness** in the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused because entities with the same ID are considered to be about the same thing, and they are merged.

You are trying to say that a trail in a breadcrumb is also an AutomotiveBusiness.

Change the IDs in the breqadcrumb trail so that they relate to the URLs for the WebPages in the trail.